# Error deploying new project with gcloud beta run deploy service-name --source

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I created a fresh project and ran

`gcloud beta run deploy service-name --source . --platform managed --allow-unauthenticated --project my-new-project`

and got this error

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.run.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: could not resolve storage source: googleapi: Error 403: 522972761233@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object., forbidden
```

What can be?

Comment: Besides using the solution from guillaume blaquiere, could you also specify a bucket to save your logs into? (creating a new bucket) it seems that sometimes that helps to solving this issue. You can do this with the command flag on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit#--gcs-log-dir)

Answer (score 0):

Use the projectID and not the project name in your command line.